# Why does it say $\mu$ is a Borel measure?

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

[image]

[image]

These pictures are from Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis.

In 2.14 Theorem, $\mathfrak{M}$ contains all Borel sets in $X$, which means $\mathfrak{M}$ may contain a set that is not Borel.

In 2.17 Theorem (b), $\mathfrak{M}$ may contain a set which is not Borel, why does it say $\mu$ is a regular Borel measure on $X$?

In 2.18 Theorem, $\lambda$ is a positive Borel measure on $X$, $\mu$ is defined on a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak{M}$ that may contain a set which is not Borel. Why does it get $\lambda=\mu$?

Comment: In 2.17 and 2.18 it means the restriction of $\mu$ to the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets.

Comment: I took the liberty to change all your \mathfrak R into \mathfrak M to make it more consistent with Rudin's notation (which apparently is \mathfrak M from a different package).

Comment: @D_S How do you know that? Where does it say that?

Comment: A Borel measure is by definition a measure defined on the Borel subsets.  So what I said is the only possible interpretation which makes sense.